# AWS S3 bucket to Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am getting a "IP address not found" error.

I had an S3 bucket pointing to my domain, and it was working.

I deleted the S3 bucket and rebuilt it. Since then, I can't get it to work again.

In fact, I have gone over all of the steps again.

1. Create the S3 bucket (example.com and www.example.com)
2. Made those two public.
3. Assign one to be the host, and the other to redirect
4. Added bucket policies for both

In Route 53

1. Created a hosted zone
2. Added 'A' alias record pointing to my S3 bucket (one for each) assigned those to the S3 bucket in the dropdown

In Cloudfront

1. Created a distribution pointing to the S3 origin with the additional names plus a wildcard.

I also have verified the certificate necessary to do this step in the Certificate Manager.

The problem seems to be that when I deleted the bucket, (I did this to change regions).
Somehow, it refuses to connect to the new set of IPs.

I have done this before, (not the deleting part) and had success.

If anyone knows what the issue could be, or if you think it is an AWS thing that is just taking a very long time to update globally, please let me know. I don't know how to check the status of that sort of thing. And I don't want to interrupt anything that may be working behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could just be a timing issue. Check again after 24-48 hours. Is the Domain Name working, if you go directly without using CloudFront?

Comment: It is not working. I am currently just pointing to the 's3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' selection under 'A' alias in Route 53.

Comment: Is the bucket name the same as the domain name? So if your domain is `example.com`, the bucket name is also `example.com`? First step is to confirm it works via the website URL, then check that it works via the Domain Name. Finally, check that it works via CloudFront. I presume you followed the steps on [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)?

Comment: Yes. Very precisely those steps. If I have the hosted zone, and the only options that appear in the 'A' record dropdown are my S3 buckets respectively (example.com and www.example.com ) and my Cloudfront distribution, does that not mean that it is finding it ok? I just can't think of a configuration that is interfering or not allowing it to find them. I want to start over on the S3 bucket side, but I'm afraid of introducing new variables and resetting the TTL clock. Thank you for the link. I will comb through it again.

Comment: I went through the steps for setting up both S3 buckets. I was able to access the site from the example.com endpoint, but I was not able to access it from the www.example.com redirect endpoint. It appeared to be going to Route 53. Even though those 'A' records have been deleted. Should I be able to see that redirect via the endpoints?

Comment: After some further reading, the AWS docs recommended doing a WHOIS query. I saw that the NameServers were different.(Probably from my original hosted zone) I added the correct ones to the NS record (Added not Replaced) in my Route 53 hosted zone. I am hoping that the TTL does not take another 2 days to see if it works. Does this make sense to try?

Comment: OK. So here [https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=797483] and here[ https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-dns-website-unreachable/?icmpid=support_rt_kc_articles] are where the answer lives. It was all about matching the NS and SOA settings and the order in which it is done.